# Margin of Error for poll that allows selecting multiple options?

Tags: confidence-interval, survey, polling

I have a poll with a known sample size (let's say n=1000) which has results that look like this:

`Which foods do you like?
Apple Pie - 80%
Cheese Pizza - 65%
Cheese - 70%`

Note the percentages don't add up to 100% because voters were allowed to pick multiple options.

I would like to compute margins of error for each option and am wondering whether it's sufficient to apply a binomial MOE --- e.g. `z*sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)` --- for each option individually.

My intuition is that yes, I can do it this way, since each option can essentially be treated as it's own binary question: Do you like Apple Pie (Yes/No)? Do you like Cheese Pizza (Yes/No)? and so on.

However, the thing that's tripping me up is the they could very well be correlated. Respondents who select Cheese are far more likely to select Cheese Pizza than those who did not select Cheese.

Does this correlation make calculating the MoE for each option not worthwhile?